# Any other ways apart from Window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know by using `Window.location.href`. I can pass variables in my html, for instance:

```
window.location.href=getone_url+'?proId='+proId
```

However now, I want something similar, but without refreshing the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values in an array.

Then you can retrieve the values from the same array.

**Working Example:**

```js
var listOfNumbers = [];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var numberDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

function addNumberToList() {
    listOfNumbers[listOfNumbers.length] = this.textContent;
}

function memoryList() {
var textList = listOfNumbers.join(', ');
window.alert('The numbers you clicked were (in order): ' + textList);
listOfNumbers = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < numberDivs.length; i++) {
    numberDivs[i].addEventListener('click',addNumberToList,false);
}

button.addEventListener('click',memoryList,false);
```

```css
div {
float: left;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 3px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
border-radius: 6px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
clear: left;
}

div:hover {
background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
cursor: pointer;
}

button {
margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>

<button type="button">Tell me what I clicked</button>
```

Comment: I think the OP is talking about going to a server-side database.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misled you. I want something like session in php, so i can use it whenever I want before it expires.

Comment: If you generate an array (see the example above) you can post the array from one page to the next. If you don't refresh the page, the array is immediately accessible.

Comment: Thank you, Rounin. But this is not what I want. I think I will just store that in a session and call it upon.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is your best bet.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misled you. I want something like session in php, so i can use it whenever I want before it expires.

Answer (score 0):

use this: `jQuery.post(getone_url, { proId: 6 })`

Comment: Hi, my problem is not sending it to the server side. I want to get the value of proId in a static page, but i do not where I can store this value and use it whenever I need to.

Comment: you can store it in session or local storage - google it

Answer (score 0):

you could use cookies to store value at frontend. futhermore, cookies could be shared with backend (there are some possible issues with syncronization timing, but they could be solved)